# Can I run Selenium webdriver using Firefox as the browser?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I would like to set up the Raspberry Pi as a client that exclusively runs FireFox as a client in a Selenium grid.

Has anyone tried and got this to work?

Are there any tips or pitfalls that I will need to be aware of?

Answer (score 7):

You either need to have enable X or better you can run Selenium webdriver on Raspberry Pi in headless mode with [`xvfb`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb). For this you need the following:

Install required APT packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install iceweasel
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

Install required `pip` packages:

```
sudo pip install selenium
sudo pip install PyVirtualDisplay
sudo pip install xvfbwrapper
```

Install [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases):

```
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.23.0/geckodriver-v0.23.0-arm7hf.tar.gz
tar -xvzf geckodriver*
chmod +x geckodriver
sudo mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/
```

Then start with the following minimal Python:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/')
driver.quit()

display.stop()
```

Comment: I also needed to download the appropriate geckodriver for my Firefox version (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.17.0/geckodriver-v0.17.0-arm7hf.tar.gz) and add to the system path

Answer (score 5):

I got Raspberry and Selenium working using

Python, Selenium Firefox driver, and Iceweasel

so if you sudo apt-get install iceweasel,
then you have a firefox-based browser that will work with the Selenium firefox driver.

Would this help you?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance... It is 2019, does this still hold true?

Comment: @jww I don't know, haven't tried it since 2014. But I can't come up with a reason why it would not still work. Can you?

Answer (score 1):

Following on from @Techraf you need to install the geckodriver.

Here is the latest version supported for Rasp Pi:

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.23.0

Download geckodriver-v0.23.0-arm7hf.tar.gz

This is the latest release supporting arm7hf, which I believe is required for Selenium on Rasp Pi.

You need to inform your script to load the geckodriver. Like so

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '/home/pi/Downloads/geckodriver')
driver.get('http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/')
```